# What was Michael Emerson actually eating with the Lost Boys?

Tags: the-lost-boys

There is a scene in the Lost Boys cave where David (Keifer Sutherland) and/or the Lost Boys play a prank on Michael (Jason Patric) while they were eating out of Chinese take out boxes. The contents of Michael's box toggled between being rice/maggots and noodles/worms. What was the actual food in the boxes? Were they eating Chinese take out, or were the vampires all eating maggots and making Michael think it was Chinese food?

Comment: I don't have a source to cite, but it was actually supposed to be noodles. The scene was a nod to the trope about vampires having the power of illusion.

Comment: @Omegacron: It's impossible to find a source for this. Evey description of the scene I can find literally skips the food and goes straight to the wine. Which the average teenage boy would probably do, granted, but it's not how the scene plays out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

James already has an accurate answer for you, but here's a transcript of the scene from the film's screenplay:

> Marko suddenly arrives bearing cartons of take-out food.
>
> **MARKO:** Chow time!
>
> *David takes the cartons from his hand.*
>
> **DAVID:** Chinese! Good choice. 
>   *He pops the lid on one of the cartons and approaches Michael with it.*
>
> **DAVID:** Guests first.
>
> *Michael hesitates.*
>
> **DAVID:** It's only rice. Don't you like rice? 300 million Chinese people can't be wrong.
>
> *Michael takes the carton warily and David immediately turns his back on him, passing out food to the others. Michael takes a mouthful of
>   rice using the plastic spoon provided.  The others begin to eat as
>   well.*
>
> **DAVID:** So how do you like those maggots, Michael?
>
> **MICHAEL:** What?...
>
> **DAVID:** You're eating maggots. How do they taste?
>
> *Michael looks at his food.*
>
> *CLOSE ON THE CARTON - A thousand wiggling maggots, squirming and sliding over each other. MICHAEL spits out his mouthful in horror and
>   revulsion and throws the carton to the ground. But as the carton
>   spills out, we see that it is just rice after all.*
>
> *The boys LAUGH UPROARIOUSLY.  Michael looks mortified. Star gets to her feet.*
>
> **STAR:** Leave him alone.
>
> **DAVID:** Sorry, Michael.  No hard feelings, huh? *(offers a new carton of food)* Here. Try these noodles.
>
> *Michael looks at the noodles and his expression turns to one of disgust.*
>
> **MICHAEL:** Ugh!
>
> *CLOSE ON THE CARTON - A hundred squirming earthworms fill the container.*
>
> *David tilts back his head and pours the contents of the carton into his mouth. The slimy bundle of worms slides slowly across his lips.*
>
> *Michael looks on with a sick expression. He grabs David's arm.*
>
> **MICHAEL:** Don't!  Stop!
>
> **DAVID:** Why? (beat) They're only noodles.
>
> *David shows Michael the carton again.  And sure enough, they are only noodles. Michael is baffled. The boys have a good, long laugh at his expense.*

Oddly enough, this ability to make others see what they want is never mentioned again, neither in this film nor the two sequels. And that's despite several situations where it would have proved quite useful. It's most likely just a nod to the trope that vampires have the generic "power of illusion".

Comment: Michael's first clue that something is not right: David's estimate of China's population is way off - it was more like 1 billion in 1987, not 300 million. :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_population

Comment: @RobertF - true. He may have actually said "a billion" in the movie. Screenplays are rarely 100% accurate compared to the final result. I have it at home, guess I'll to watch it tonight :P

Comment: @RobertF He does say 'a billion' in the movie: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A80j2BuMaU

Answer (score 6):

They were eating Chinese take-out and making him think it was maggots. This was to set up the subsequent scene, where he won't believe the female vampire's claim that the 'wine' is actually David's blood. You can tell because the female vampire is honest with Michael about the wine, so she wouldn't have lied to him about the Chinese food (which I thought was rice, not noodles, but it's been a while since I watched it).

Comment: They had both rice and chow mein noodles, but I think the one Michael had was rice.

Comment: @Omegacron Ty. I edited the question.

Comment: I believe your assertion about the sequence leading to the "blood wine" is spot on. As stated in the @Omegacron answer, there was rice (maggots) and noodles (worms) both. +1 for a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The illusions were maggots & worms. Vampires CAN eat human food but it's tasteless to them. David played the mind tricks on Michael in case Star tried to warn him of the real contents of what was in the bottle.

Answer (score -1):

I have always wondered if it was really maggots and worms as a snack since they are vampires and need blood to survive and the illusion was made to make it appear as actual rice and noodles so Michael wouldn't see what they are actually eating and then they stopped the illusion long enough for him to see that it was actually maggots and worms to mess with his mind and to add to the story of vamps being able to get inside someone's thoughts,but after all if Michael knew they were really eating maggots and worms,he would never drink the bloodwine and it would give them away perhaps before he was befriended, but also it could work the other way to cover incase the female was to tell him the wine was blood he would not believe her and drink it anyway as he did. But after all,they are vampires and can not eat regular food and the worms were the type of worms called blood worms so it really could have been maggots and worms and the illusion of real food but could Ben actually food and made to look like maggots/worms. Guess for the watcher to interpret his own way